# No results during a search through Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having the problem to pull out data from my database through a search field. I'm trying to protect my searchfield against Sql injection at the same time. Adding data to my database is working fine, and I think i did fine safetywise. Yet, pulling the data out seems to be harder.

All i'm trying to achieve is getting all the data from the person. I'm looking for "Bart" in my search field, so show me all the data from all the Barts in my database.

This is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table class="table_form">
        <form method="POST" action="test.php">
          <tr>
            <td>Voornaam: </td><td><input type="text" name="Voornaam"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Achternaam: </td><td><input type="text" name="Achternaam"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Adres: </td><td><input type="text" name="Adres"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Discipline: </td><td><input type="text" name="Discipline"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Graad: </td><td><input type="text" name="Graad"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Voeg toe aan databank: </td><td><input type="submit" name="Adddb" value="Bevestigen"></td>
          </tr>
         </form>

      </table>


      <table class="table_form">
            <form method="POST" action="test.php">
                <tr>
                    <td>Zoeken</td><td><input type="text" name="Voornaam" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bevestigen</td><td><input type="submit" name="zoeken" /></td>
                </tr>

            </form>
      </table>

<div class="field">
<?php
  require_once 'isset.php';
?>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP

```
<?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $db_con= new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    $db_con->set_charset("utf8");
    if($db_con->connect_error) die ("(" . $db_con->connect_error . " Error during connection");


    if(isset($_POST['Adddb'])){
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (Voornaam, Achternaam, Adres, Actief, Discipline, graad) VALUES(?,?,?,NOW(),?,?)");


        $stmt->bind_param("sssii",$voornaam, $achternaam, $adres, $discipline,$graad);

        $voornaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
        $achternaam = $_POST['Achternaam'];
        $adres = $_POST['Adres'];
        $discipline = $_POST['Discipline'];
        $graad = $_POST['Graad'];
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "New records created successfully";

        $stmt->close();
        $db_con->close();

    }


    if(isset($_POST['zoeken'])){

        $stmte = $db_con->prepare="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Voornaam = (?)";
        $stmte->bind_param("s", $zoeknaam);

        $zoeknaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
        $stmte->execute();

        echo $zoeknaam;



    }







?>
```

Am i wrong to think that i'm not fetching something? And that is the reason i'm not getting anything?

EDIT ------>

Edited version as suggested below: Errors are gone but no results show up:

```
<?php

    require_once 'login.php';
    $db_con= new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    $db_con->set_charset("utf8");
    if($db_con->connect_error) die ("(" . $db_con->connect_error . " Error during connection");

if(isset($_POST['zoeken'])){

    $zoeknaam = $_POST['Zoek']; // declare the input here
    $stmte = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Voornaam = ?");
    $stmte->bind_param("s", $zoeknaam); // then use inside here
    $stmte->execute();


    $rows = $stmte->num_rows;


    for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmte, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $row['Voornaam'] . '<br/>';
    }







    /*if($stmte->num_rows > 0) {
    $results = $stmte->get_result();
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row['Achternaam'] . '<br/>';
        // and other columns
    }*/
}



?>
```

Comment: assign this $zoeknaam before the bindparam $stmte->bind_param("s", $zoeknaam);

Comment: You are correct, you execute your statement but you don't fetch any rows from the result set. Check for example `$stmte->num_rows` to see how many results you really have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the results properly by using `->get_result()`. After that, you would be able to use `->fetch_assoc()`. Example:

```
$zoeknaam = $_POST['Voornaam']; // declare the input here
$stmte = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Voornaam = ?");
$stmte->bind_param("s", $zoeknaam); // then use inside here
$stmte->execute();

if($stmte->num_rows > 0) {
    $results = $stmte->get_result();
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['Voornaam'] . '<br/>';
        echo $row['Achternaam'] . '<br/>';
        // and other columns
    }
}
```

If unfortunately, you do not have `mysqlnd` in your environment (if `->get_result()` turns out the be Call to undefined method). Here's another way:

```
$zoeknaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
$stmte = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Voornaam = ?");
$stmte->bind_param("s", $zoeknaam);
$stmte->execute();

// get all columns
$meta = $stmte->result_metadata(); 
while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
    $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmte, 'bind_result'), $params);
while ($stmte->fetch()) { 
    echo $row['Voornaam'] . '<br/>';
    echo $row['Achternaam'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I added this code, the errors are gone but nothing is coming up as a result.

Comment: @MichaelDesmadril if `get->result()` doesn't work use the alternative method below

Comment: Working now!All i have to do know is understand what is happening in your 2nd section of code.

Pitty ->Get_result() isn't working, seems like a decent way of handeling things! Apparently i'm using the wrong library for this function to work.

Comment: @MichaelDesmadril yeah, personally i prefer the first method (`->get_result()`). but since you don't have `mysqlnd` it will not. the second method simply just gets all the column names, then basically loads it inside the `bind_result`. then when you `->fetch()` you can call it like you normally would do inside a while loop with `mysqli_fetch_*` functions. glad this helped